# Python: cómo crear una matriz 2D en la que cada elemento sea una tupla de tamaño variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matrices, matemáticas

Esta es una pregunta un poco compleja, y no sabía que titulo poner, así que agradecería lo primero si alguien sabe definir mejor este concepto que se sienta libre de cambiar el título del post.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Yo tengo una matriz, en este caso:

```
matriz=[[1,2,4],[6,8,8],[9,10,12]]
```

Lo que quiero conseguir con esto, es que cada grid contenga una cantidad de números que determine el grid en sí. Me refiero a algo parecido a esto:

```
matriz[0][0]=1

matriz[0][1]=2,3

matriz[0][2]=4,5,6,7

matriz[1][0]=8,9,10,11,12,13

matriz[1][1]=14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21

...
```

Gracias por la ayuda, llevo un buen rato intentando conseguir este resultado, un saludo.

Comment: @abulafia gracias por la correción, ya lo he solucionado, pero lo que no se como programar es el ejercicio en sí, es decir, se plantearlo, pero no plasmarlo en python. Un saludo, y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente, el código siguiente hace lo que pides:

```
numeros=[[1,2,4],[6,8,8],[9,10,12]]
matriz = []

inicio = 1
for fila in numeros:
  m_fila = []
  for n in fila:
    m_fila.append(tuple(range(inicio, inicio+n)))
    inicio += n
  matriz.append(m_fila)
```

Resultado:

```
>>> matriz
[[(1,), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)],
 [(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13),
  (14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
  (22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)],
 [(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38),
  (39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48),
  (49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60)]]
```

Ahora bien, ¡que me aspen si entiendo para qué sirve esto! :-)

#### Versión usando numpy

```
import numpy as np
numeros=np.array([[1,2,4],[6,8,8],[9,10,12]])
matriz = np.zeros(numeros.shape, dtype=object)

inicio = 1
for i, fila in enumerate(numeros):
  for j, n in enumerate(fila):
    matriz[i][j] = tuple(range(inicio, inicio+n))
    inicio += n
```

```
>>> print(matriz)
[[(1,) (2, 3) (4, 5, 6, 7)]
 [(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13) (14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
  (22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)]
 [(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38)
  (39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48)
  (49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60)]]
```